# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : cors error on HttpPost only with authorization policy

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, preflight, azure-app-registration

I have added my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application to Azure "App registrations" and I'm able to login using the Microsoft WebUI and perform `GET` requests to obtain e.g. my views.

The application is hosted on IIS 8.5.

I've also defined a few App roles in my Azure App registration panel.
When I click on a button that sends a `POST` request though, a preflight request is sent and I see the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[omitted]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[omitted]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F[omitted]%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&[omitted] from origin '[omitted]' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried:

1. Editing `web.config` to exclude handling `OPTIONS` requests from the default ASP.NET Core handler and removing handlers like `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0`
2. Adding `UseCors` to `Program.cs`
3. Handling all `OPTIONS` requests in `Program.cs` so that they receive a 200 response
4. Checked the Web URIs I've added under Azure App Registrations (which should work, as I'm able to login...)
5. Something else I don't recall (but from StackOverflow posts related to Cors, App registrations etc.)

But I've removed many of the above as they don't seem to work.

I don't understand why `GET` requests to my MVC controllers have no problem, while `POST` requests fail (because a preflight request is sent and hates me, while no preflight request is sent before a `GET` request).

Also, no SPA app is involved here, just plain MVC with views that reference ordinary vanilla js files (containing some fetch calls to POST).

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton... // adding my services like db repository etc.

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("roles", "Admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("Purchaser", policy => policy.RequireClaim("roles", "Purchaser", "Admin"));
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

//...

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// app.MapAreaControllerRoute and stuff

app.Run();
```

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
                <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
                <remove name="WebDav"/>
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TaskBridgePortal.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"/>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <!--add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" /-->
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

A sample controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Orders")]
[Area/*..*/]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ReportController(/* ... */)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpPost] // fails
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadReportAsync([FromBody] DownloadReportRequest request)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ReportAsync(bool returnView = true) // doesn't fail
    {
        //... 
        return View(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please share what order policy do for your codes? And how you  click on a button that sends a POST request? By using ajax or just the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

You should register your CORS with the necessary URL ("*" for a lot of URLs)

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy  =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com");
        });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Also, you can register CORS for static files

```
builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://example.com");
    };
});
```

More information you can find below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0